# Webpack-dev-server how to include bundle

Tags: webpack, frontend, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to switch from using `webpack` in my dev environment to using `webpack-dev-server`.

Everything works fine in the sense that the bundle is correctly created and lies in memory on `http://localhost:8080/path/to/bundle`. But I can not access this path since the browser blocks mixed content, and the file is not accessible via `https`.

So that is my first problem, but give that I can fix that issue, i can not just include the file by saying

`<script src='http://localhost:8080/path/to/bundle'>` because that would not work when i push this to production.

I have watched and read a bunch of different tutorials but I can't seem to really understand how this works. For reference, this is my config file:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./npm_views/entry.js",
    output: {
        filename: "npm_bundle.js",
        publicPath: '/build',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build/"),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                include: /npm_views/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ['react' ,'env'],
                    plugins: ['transform-class-properties']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my issue and I'd like to leave a guideline for anyone else switching from `webpack` to `webpack-dev-server`:

**First you'll want to add a public path to your `webpack.config.js` file:**

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    output: {
        ...
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: '/build',
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

`webpack-dev-server` spins up a server running on port 8080 with the file loaded and accessible from the publicPath + filename that you have specified. So if you want to include it **you will have to add a script tag like this one:**

`<script src='http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js'>`

or more generally

`<script src='http://localhost:8080/publicPath/filename'>`

Now the first issue is that in production you will not be using webpack-dev-server. You will use webpack which creates a build file in the specified path. So **you will have to do something like this in your html that includes the bundle:**

```
<?php

$BundlePath = IsThisMyLocalMachine ? 'http://localhost:8080/publicPath/filename' : 'build\bundle.js'

?>

<html>
...
<script src='<?php echo $BundlePath ?>'>
..
</html>
```

Now the last issue is that if your website uses `https` and `webpack-dev-server` serves the build on `http` the browser will block it as mixed content.

Getting around this is pretty simple though. **You just need to tell `webpack-dev-server` to serve content on `https` by adding this to your config file:**

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    output: {
        ...
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: '/build',
        ...
    },
    devServer: {
        https: true,
    },
    ...
}
```

Now if you change all those `http://localhost:8080/` to `https://localhost:8080/` everything should work fine

Comment: for anyone else coming here looking for this and regarding problem 1,  Webpack now has a devServer option: `{writeToDisk: true}` which will let you just import from `/publicPath/filename`